# How to use custom OutputPath in Symfonys WebPack Encore?

Tags: symfony, webpack

I am working on a project using `Symfony 6.0` and added WebPack Encore to the project, following the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html).

In `webpack.config.js` I used `setOutputPath` and `setPublicPath` to set a custom assets dir, other than the default `public/build` folder:

```
Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/assets/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/assets/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')
```

This works fine. When running `npm run dev` the files are now creates in `public/assets/build` instead of in the default `public/build` folder.

However, after updating the config in this way the twig methods `{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}` and `{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}` generate no more output. No script and style information is added to the generated HTML.

So, how to properly setup Encore to use a folder other than the default `public/build`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer myself... :-) I will leave it here in case other stumble over the same problem:

One has to update the `config/packages/webpack_encore.yaml` file as well:

```
webpack_encore:
    # The path where Encore is building the assets - i.e. Encore.setOutputPath()
    output_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/assets/build'

framework:
    assets:
        json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/assets/build/manifest.json'
```

While I do not really understand why it is necessary to set the same config at three different locations, this is the way to go.